# Pass name of sorted column in DataTable with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I need to create dataTable with `serverSide: true`. When I try to get the request on my endpoint on the server side, I get something like `0: {column: 5, dir: "asc"}` in `order` field. But I really want to get the name of the columns, not the number of column that I sort by. Like this `0: {column: "id", dir: "asc"}`.
There is my code below:

```
vat table = $('#foo').DataTable({
paging: true,
pagingType: "numbers",
serverSide: true,
ajax: {
  "url": uri_api
},
order: [
  [1, "asc"]
],
columnDefs: [
  <my columns here>
 ]
});
```

I will be really appreciated If you helped me with that.

Comment: For what do you need the name? You should know the name as you created the table

Comment: The standard `serverSide` request includes the name of the `data` field for each column index. So, as well as being sent the index `order[0][dir] = "asc"`, you also know that column index 0 is using a specific data value - for example: `columns[0][data] = "id"`. If that is not sufficient, then you can also give each column a [custom `name`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.name) - and that is also returned with each request: `columns[0][name] = "my_custom_id_name_here"`. With either of these pieces of information you can map the column index to a data or name value.

Comment: For more information see the [sent parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) documentation. If that does not meet your needs, can you clarify the question?